# Display activity as a popup window

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-theme

I have a service that starts an activity as a dialog/popup window from my app. It works generally ok.

When my app is closed (not in recents), the popup will overlay any underlying app with a transparent surrounding background.

But the issue comes when my app was minimized in the background and I'm using another app, then I click on the service button to display the popup, it brings my app back into the front with the popup over my app (not the previous third-party app).

How can I prevent this behavior and make my activity overly any window regardless of my app's state?

This is the theme I'm using

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the popup dialog has nothing to do with your app (and you want it to be separate and distinct from your app in case your app is already running), then you want to do the following:

In the manifest, set the `taskAffinity` for this dialog-themed `Activity` to an empty string, set the `excludeFromRecents` flag and the `noHistory` flag like this:

```
<activity android:name=".DialogThemedActivity"
          android:taskAffinity=""
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:noHistory="true"
          ... />
```

Declaring the `Activity` like this ensures that it is not associated with any existing task that your app is currently in. It also ensures that this task will not end up in the list of recent tasks (so that the user doesn't accidentally start the `Activity` again from the list of recent tasks) and that the task will be deleted as soon as the user navigates away from the dialog-themed `Activity`.

Now, in your `Service`, make sure that when you launch the `Activity` you add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DialogThemedActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it out. Simply adding this flag to the launching intent

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

Comment: This is actually a really bad way to solve this problem, and will probably create more problems for you in the future. For example, if you do this you will end up with 2 tasks in the list of recent tasks, confusing the user. See my answer instead.